# I want a file to look bigger than it actually is

Tags: properties

I have a text file that is 2mb and i want to make the file *seem* to be bigger (20 or 50mb). Basicaly I want a 2mb file to be described as/look like a 50mb file. I would like to know is there a way to do so, without actually using up storage. Ive looked online and tried a few things on my PC myself but i haven't got anything good apart form being able to change the date. Is there a way to make the file look bigger than it actually is?